# Why the user cannot download the app from Google Play from South Korea

Tags: android, google-play, samsung

The user from South Korea cannot download the app from Google Play even though in Google Console the app is targeted. It says 'you cannot use this app'. Fresh samsung phone, the software is updated. Could you please brainstorm any ideas? Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV7Jc.png)

Brainstorming ideas.